# What happens to stock warrants on acquisition?

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition, warrants

I am invested heavily in warrants within a mid-cap biotech company. Due to the cash position of many large-cap biotechs like Moderna and Pfizer, I am assuming they will start to make some acquisitions for some high growth groundbreaking drugs. I have about 210,000 warrants at an average cost of about $0.95. I have different warrants with different exercise prices ranging from $1.4 to $5.75 with about a 2 year expiry.

If a company decides to acquire the company I'm invested in, what happens to the warrants? Will they be worthless if the company is bought for under the exercise price? Or do I get some sort of premium on my warrants for having time value still in them?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a merger for shares, the warrants will be adjusted to reflect the share terms of the merger and will continue to trade.

If it's a cash buyout then warrant expiration is accelerated and the warrant will be worth its intrinsic value if in-the-money and worthless if out-of-the-money.

Comment: But how can you accelerate warrants that are out of the money? If I buy a warrant, or am an early stage investor and my warrants that are out of the money; how can a company accelerate my warrants out of the money? That seems illegal. I'm sure theres rights for warrant holders not to be accelerated out of the money. Especially if a warrant holder pays for the right to hold the warrant for years.